# proper way to perform a package install or upgrade with chef

Tags: chef-infra

The following chef recipe code aims to **install or upgrade** a given package named *something*. The objective of this recipe is to:

- perform an initial install of the package/service
- keep the service running whenever there is no need to upgrade the package
- upgrade the service if a new version of the RPM is available, in such event, restart the service after the upgrade

Somehow the install appears to work well, but in the event of an **upgrade** chef client reports the following error related to the lack of init.d script, so it appears that the package gets unistalled and not reinstalled properly:

```
ERROR: service[something] (something::something-deploy line 36) 
had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Service: service[something]: 
unable to locate the init.d script!
```

recipe code of interest:

```
package 'something' do
  action :upgrade
  notifies :restart, "service[something]", :delayed
end

service 'something' do
  action :enable
end
```

Comment: dosen't the service name changed during the upgrade ? (tomcat to tomcat7 for example) ? which would explain why the init.d script is not found.

Comment: The RPM name changed, but not the service per se... I changed the format of naming from *something-1.0-230.rpm* to *something-2017.05.09.231-231.rpm* where 230 and 231 are build numbers. I am not sure if that would cause the service name to change

Comment: I can't guess what your rpm does, inspect the filesytem to ensure what is there and what is not. But if chef can't find the init.d script, it means something did remove it somewhere, and that's not chef, either yum did (used by the package resource) or your rpm inner code have a problem setting it up. With a faked recipe I can't tell, that's just guessing

Answer (score 1):

The issue relates to the .spec file used to generate the RPM. In such file the macro %preun ( which is a pre-uninstall section ) is executed on both **installations** and **upgrades** of a package, therefore it was removing the linux service /etc/init.d/something file also when upgrading

To prevent the above, the rpm utilities have a argument which can be used to limit the scope of the **%preun** and **%postun** sections, where *$1 == 0* it indicates the scenario to be un unistall and *$1 == 1* regards an upgrade.

The solution was to

```
%preun
if [ $1 == 0 ]; then 
  #cleanup
fi
```